# How to group by column values into Row and column header and then sum the value

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

Below is my input and output `.txt` files.

I want to group by the data by `StatusDate` and `Method`.
And then sum the values based on the `StatusDate` and `Method`.

**Input.txt**

```
No,Date,MethodStatus,Key,StatusDate,Hit,CallType,Method,LastMethodType
112,12/15/16,Suceess,Geo,12/15/16,1,Static,GET,12/15/16
113,12/18/16,Suceess,Geo,12/18/16,1,Static,GET,12/18/16
114,12/19/16,AUTHORIZED,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,GET,12/19/16
115,12/19/16,AUTHORIZED,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,GET,12/19/16
116,12/19/16,Suceess,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,PUT,12/19/16
117,12/19/16,Suceess,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,PUT,12/19/16
118,12/19/16,Waiting,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,GET,12/19/16
119,12/19/16,AUTHORIZED,Geo,12/19/16,1,Static,GET,12/19/16
120,12/17/16,Suceess,Geo,12/17/16,1,Static,GET,12/17/16
121,12/17/16,Suceess,Geo,12/17/16,1,Static,GET,12/17/16
130,12/16/16,Suceess,Geo,12/16/16,1,Static,GET,12/16/16
```

**Out.txt**

```
StatusDate,12/15/16,12/16/16,12/17/16,12/17/16,12/18/16,12/19/16,12/19/16,12/19/16,12/19/16,12/19/16,12/19/16,Grand Total
GET,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,,,9
PUT,,,,,,,,,,1,1,2
Grand Total,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,11
```

I'm using `awk` and splitting the data by `awk -F, '{if($8=="GET") print }'`, then calculating the sum value.
Since the file size is huge, there is a delay.

Is it possible to do everything in one step? So the file operation will be reduced?

Comment: Can you show some code that is doing this? Otherwise, how does anybody know how to make it more efficient?

Comment: What _values_ do you want to _sum_? How do you get the values in your **Out.txt**, for example the `GET` value `1` on `12/17/16` although there are two input records for this `StatusDate`?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ',' '
   /GET/{ Get[ $2]++}
   /PUT}{ Put[ $2]++}
   {Total[$2]++}

   END {
     printf( "StatusDate')
     for (d in Total) printf( ",%s", d)
     printf( "\nTotal GET")
     for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Get[d])
     printf( " PUT")
     for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Put[d])
     printf( " Grand Total")
     for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Total[d])
     printf( "\n")
     }
   ' Input.txt
```

- store data in 3 array at each line
- several loop to disply the result at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use associative array to keep track of aggregations.

```
NR == 1 {
    next
}

$8 == "GET" {
    Get[$2]++
    g++
    Total[$2]++
    next
}

$8 == "PUT" {
    Put[$2]++
    p++
    Total[$2]++
    next
}

END {
    printf( "StatusDate")
    for (d in Total) printf( ",%s", d)
    printf( ",Grand Total\nGET")
    for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Get[d])
    printf( ",%d\nPUT", g)
    for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Put[d])
    printf( ",%d\nGrand Total",p)
    for (d in Total) printf( ",%d", Total[d])
    printf( ",%d\n",g+p)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 {printf "%s",$8$2; t="Total"; v[t]; next} 
                 {d[$2]; v[$8]; a[$2,$8]++; a[$2,t]++} 
           END   {n=asorti(d,ds); 
                  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", FS ds[i]; 
                  print ""; 
                  for(k in v) 
                    {printf "%s", k; 
                     for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", FS a[ds[i],k]; 
                     print ""}}' file


MethodDate,12/15/16,12/16/16,12/17/16,12/18/16,12/19/16
PUT,,,,,2
GET,1,1,2,1,4
Total,1,1,2,1,6
```

Comment: Output is not matching with expected result, Total value is incorrect